# Javascript regexp issue - matches only part of result

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm using this regex

```
<a [^>]*href[ ]*=[ ]*\"|'[^>]\"|'[^>]*>
```

to search in example string:

```
 idhasidhioashdoihas <a onclick=alert('blablabla') href='www.hello.com'
 onclick=alert('blablabla') > asdfsgdufisdugfusdg
```

It should match

```
<a onclick=alert('blablabla') href='www.hello.com'onclick=alert('blablabla') >
```

but it only matches

```
'blablabla') href='www.hello.com' onclick=alert('blablabla') >
```

Any idea where is the problem?

Comment: `[ ]*` should really be `\s*`

Comment: why not simply `/<a.+?>/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `|` is in the wrong place:

`<a [^>]*href[ ]*=[ ]*\"|'[^>]\"|'[^>]*>` is effectively:

`<a [^>]*href[ ]*=[ ]*\"` or `'[^>]\"` or `'[^>]*>`

If you want to mark " or ' in this exact place use `[]`:

`<a [^>]*href\s*=\s*["'][^>]*["'][^>]*>`

Example:

```
a = "idhasidhioashdoihas <a onclick=alert('blablabla') href='www.hello.com' onclick=alert('blablabla') > asdfsgdufisdugfusdg";
a.match(/<a [^>]*href\s*=\s*["'][^>]*["'][^>]*>/)
["<a onclick=alert('blablabla') href='www.hello.com' onclick=alert('blablabla') >"]
```

Comment: OK, that worked. Thanks so much.
Just need to add \ ahead of "

Answer (score 0):

You don't correctly test for the two possible attribute value delimiters. You can use this one :

```
/<a [^>]*href[ ]*=[ ]*[\"']?[^>][\"']?[^>]*>/
```

I just changed `\"|'` to `[\"']?` (note that it's possible not to have quotes at all, hence the `?`)

Answer (score 0):

The character classes you use are not always appropriate and you must surround your alternation by a group (ie: `(?:'|")`), but you don't need it. You can try this, with the same idea:

```
<a (?:[^h>]+|h(?!ref))*\bhref\s*=\s*["'][^"']*["'][^>]*>
```

But if you want only to find a link tag, you can use `<a.+?>` as thg435 suggests it.

(Note that the href value is not always between quotes:

```
<a (?:[^h>]+|h(?!ref))*\bhref\s*=\s*(?:["'][^"']*["']|[^\s>]*)[^>]*>
```

(or to be sure to have the same quotes)

```
<a (?:[^h>]+|h(?!ref))*\bhref\s*=\s*(?:(["'])(?:\\\1|[^"']+|(?!\1)["'])*\1|[^\s>]*)[^>]*>
```